# Getting the top row from a CSV when it is not a header row

Tags: c#, .net, csv, odbc

In my website I am reading a CSV file and parsing it. Now the CSV does not have a column names. It is simply a raw list of comma seperated values.

I take this file and use the ODBCDataReader class to read the rows.

The problem is that when I retrieve the first value it skips the first row of the CSV. This is probably because it considers first row as column header. But in my case there are no column headers. So every time my first row is skipped.

How can I retrieve the first row of my CSV?

**Here is the screenshot of my CSV:**

[image]

**Here is the code that I am using to parse the CSV.**

```
public string CsvParser()    
{    
    int _nNrRowsProccessed = 0;
    string connectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CSVFolder"] + ";";     
    OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);     
    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        string strFileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CSVFile"];
        string strSQL = "Select * from " + strFileName;

        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = strSQL;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string strLine = null;

        // MasterCalendar_DB.OpenMySQLConnection();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // insert data into mastercalendar
            strLine = reader[0].ToString();
            string strLine1 = reader[1].ToString();
            string strLine2 = reader[2].ToString();
            string strLine3 = reader[3].ToString();
            string[] arLine = strLine.Split(';');

           // string strAgencyPropertyID = arLine[0];
           // DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(arLine[1]);
           // Int64 nDate = (Int64)Util.ConvertToUnixTimestamp(dt);
           // String strAvailability = (arLine[2]);

            _nNrRowsProccessed++;
           // MasterCalendar_DB.Insert(strAgencyPropertyID, nDate, strAvailability);
        }     
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
       // MasterCalendar_DB.CloseMySQLConnection();
    }
    return "Success";
}
```

Comment: I will prefer to use a FileStraem instead of the OdbcConnection. This will simplify a LOT the code.

Comment: Or, instead of reinventing the wheel, use something tried-and-tested: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx

Comment: ...indeed. What exactly does the OdbcConnection do in this case? Open a text file for reading? There's simpler ways to do it.

Comment: @Felice Pollano: Not really, parsing a CSV-File can be a pain in the a**. Odbc takes at least some of this pain away.

Comment: Agree with the above, if all you are doing is reading a file then scrap the odbc and go with a file stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to have a look at [the page of the Text-Driver over at connectionstrings.org](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Providers/microsoft-text-odbc-driver).

Basically, you create a `schema.ini` in the same directory, which holds varies options. One of them is the `ColNameHeader` option, which takes a boolean.

Example from the site:

```
[customers.txt]
Format=TabDelimited
ColNameHeader=True
MaxScanRows=0
CharacterSet=ANSI
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this: [Schema.ini File (Text File Driver)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You may need to set `ColNameHeader = false`

Answer (score 0):

Reference `Microsoft.VisualBasic` and you can use [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx), which almost certainly has less dependencies than your proposed method.

```
using (var parser =
    new TextFieldParser(@"c:\data.csv")
        {
            TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited,
            Delimiters = new[] { "," }
        })
{
    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        string[] fields;
        fields = parser.ReadFields();
        //go go go!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution:

```
string strLine  = reader.GetName(0);
string strLine1 = reader.GetName(1);
string strLine2 = reader.GetName(2);
string strLine3 = reader.GetName(3);
```

reader.GetName(int i); // Gets the name of specified column.

Comment: I have decimal values like 4083.03 and when I do GetName(int index) for that column then it shows 4083#03 instead of 4083.03 So What should be done?